# Angular validate size upload

Tags: angular

I would like to implement a validation when uploading the file to check if the size exceeds 10 MB.
That is, when it reaches 10MB of attachments don't allow the user to add more attachments.

```
onFileChangeInfo(event: any){
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) { 
      const name = event.target.files[i].name;
      let size = event.target.files[i].size;
      if(size >= 1000000) {
         break;
      }
      this.myFilesInfo.push({ name, size });

    }
  }
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for what you need... do you want to disable the upload files button or something like that ?